# MYSQL - Select rows matching event code and imediate next row and calculate time date difference

Tags: mysql, datediff

So this is the table

```
ID     Date                 Event
1547   2013-05-09 16:26:02  PA
1547   2013-05-15 13:59:23  TA
1547   2013-05-21 10:16:56  EA
1547   2013-05-21 10:17:27  PM
1547   2014-01-16 11:42:12  IH
1547   2014-01-16 11:42:13  RP
1547   2014-01-21 10:01:18  MP <-
1547   2014-12-05 14:32:21  RE <-
1547   2014-12-05 14:34:24  RE
1666   2013-05-29 11:26:38  PA
1666   2013-06-04 13:38:42  TA
1666   2013-06-05 14:16:13  EA
1666   2013-08-21 10:07:08  PR
1666   2013-08-21 10:38:51  TR
1666   2013-08-21 10:38:52  MP <-
1666   2013-10-07 16:26:46  PM <-
1666   2013-10-09 14:38:51  TM
1666   2013-10-09 14:38:52  EP
1666   2013-10-25 10:29:01  IH
1666   2013-12-13 08:52:41  IH
1666   2013-12-13 08:52:43  RP
1666   2014-01-21 09:55:10  MP <-
1666   2014-05-05 15:52:34  AB <-
1666   2014-05-07 14:55:58  RD
1692   2013-06-10 14:17:17  PA
1692   2013-06-10 14:17:53  TA
1692   2013-06-10 15:01:08  EA
1692   2013-08-21 10:04:39  PR
1692   2013-08-21 10:37:38  TR
1692   2013-08-21 10:37:39  ER
1692   2013-09-26 08:33:48  PM
1692   2013-09-26 16:32:46  TM
1692   2013-09-26 16:32:47  EP
1692   2013-10-11 09:21:26  IH
1692   2013-12-19 15:29:20  IV
1692   2013-12-19 15:29:21  RP
1692   2013-12-19 15:33:19  MP <-
1692   2014-01-21 11:05:46  FX <-
1692   2014-01-22 10:16:27  RE
```

I want to select the first 'MP'event for each ID, the IMMEDIATE next one and calculate the difference in days.

The result should be:

```
ID     Date                 DaystoNextEVENT
1547   2014-01-21 10:01:18  318
1666   2013-08-21 10:38:52  47
1666   2014-01-21 09:55:10  104
1692   2013-12-19 15:33:19  33
```

I have tried to use limit but always had problems limiting the next row of the same ID with the source of the date in the match.

Comment: You could use rank() or row_number. What version of mySQL are you using?

Comment: Mysql Version 5.5

Comment: Unfortunately, due to regulations regarding validation (health industry) we cannot change the version easily. We're currently working on the update for 8. But still a few months in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a curser in a sub-query, using `order by day desc` we reverse the sort order which gives us the date of the next event. If it is the same ID we then return it in the query.

> ```
> SET @quot='';
> SET @id=0;
> select
>   id,
>   day,
>   lag_day,
>   event,
>   case when id=lag_id then
>      datediff(lag_day,day) end 
>      as days_to_next
> from
> (select
>   @id lag_id,
>   @id:=id id,
>   @quot lag_day, 
>   @quot:=day day,
>   event
> from 
>   events
> order by 
>   id , 
>   day desc) e
> where event ='MP'
> order by
>   id,
>   day;
> ```
>
> ```
>   id | day                 | lag_day             | event | days_to_next
> ---: | :------------------ | :------------------ | :---- | -----------:
> 1547 | 2014-01-21 10:01:18 | 2014-12-05 14:32:21 | MP    |          318
> 1666 | 2013-08-21 10:38:52 | 2013-10-07 16:26:46 | MP    |           47
> 1666 | 2014-01-21 09:55:10 | 2014-05-05 15:52:34 | MP    |          104
> 1692 | 2013-12-19 15:33:19 | 2014-01-21 11:05:46 | MP    |           33
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5196202f6a61e840361cda3e58eb08ea)*

Comment: Not working. I had the same problem. Unfortunately even the shown row is wrong.

Comment: I've added a second schema after the first one. Please tell me whether the query right at the bottom is okay. If it is I'll delete the first one and tidy it up. Thank you

Comment: This is EXCELLENT!!! Thank you!!!!!!!!! Perfect code and very simple.
Version tested: MySQL 5.5.27

Answer (score 1):

For version 8+:

```sql
SELECT id,
       `date`,
       DATEDIFF(LEAD(`date`) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `date`),  -- next date
                `date`                                                -- the date of MP
                ) DaystoNextEVENT
FROM table t1
WHERE event = 'MP'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL                 -- check that there is no MP earlier
                   FROM table t2
                   WHERE t1.id = t2.id
                     AND t1.`date` > t2.`date`
                     AND t2.event = 'MP' );
```

For version 5.x:

```sql
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.`date`,
       DATEDIFF(t2.`date`, t1.`date`) DaystoNextEVENT
FROM table t1                                  -- row with MP
JOIN table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id                 -- next row
             AND t1.`date` < t2.`date`
WHERE t1.event = 'MP'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL                 -- check that there is no MP earlier
                   FROM table t3
                   WHERE t1.id = t3.id
                     AND t1.`date` > t3.`date`
                     AND t3.event = 'MP' )
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL                 -- check that there is no a row
                   FROM table t4               -- between rows from tables t1 and t2
                   WHERE t1.id = t4.id
                     AND t1.`date` < t4.`date`
                     AND t4.`date` < t2.`date` );
```

Comment: Thank you but the query grouped the IDs. If you look closely, the second ID should appear 2 times.
ID      date DaystoNextEVENT
1547 2014-01-21 10:01:18 318
1666 2014-01-21 09:55:10 104
1692 2013-12-19 15:33:19 33

Comment: @Andreluiz You tell "I want to select the first 'MP'event for each ID". How it is possible that *the second ID should appear 2 times*? both rows selects "the first 'MP'event"??? Your task is contradictory. PS. If you need in all MP events - remove according NOT EXISTS condition (marked with "-- check that there is no MP earlier") simply.